# How to disable itunes writing things to my music files?

Tags: itunes

I stored my music collections ( mostly in .m4u extension) in Dropbox folders, while I play these music files in itunes, I fount that Dropbox continuously sync these files.

What does itunes write to these files and how can I disable it?

Comment: I think iTunes just updates some information in the file header, which should not be a big deal. You could try what will happen if you set the file permissions to read only. Since I never tested it and I'm also not sure about the outcome, I write this just as a comment. Of course I suggest to test only with one file (which you should duplicate before ;) )

Comment: You should set read-only permissions for these files. like by running in Terminal `chmod -R a-w music-directory-path`

Answer (score 1):

I would go to apple store in London to ask them see what they say

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. This should be left as a comment.